# How to initiate a Direct Message (Private IM) using the Slack API

Tags: slack-api, slack

Using the Slack API (webhooks, RTM, Web, doesn't matter) is it possible to initiate a DM/Private channel with a user where the private IM channel doesn't already exist?

I am aware of the API call `https://api.slack.com/methods/im.list` which will show me the private IM channels that are already open, however this is an empty list for the bot as no real user will have DM'd the bot.

Basically, we have a list of users who need to be notified of something privately by a bot, and those users will not likely have DM'd the bot before, so the private channel will not yet exist. How can we create that channel using the API?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, the fool that I am just needed to RTFM.

https://api.slack.com/methods/im.open

```
This method opens a direct message channel with another member of your Slack team.

Arguments

This method has the URL https://slack.com/api/im.open and follows the Slack Web API calling conventions.
```

Comment: @AlexCohen - the slack web api page has an example in cURL: https://api.slack.com/web (it's too long to post as a comment the actual example)

Comment: ```curl -X POST -H 'Authorization: Bearer xoxb-1234-56789abcdefghijklmnop' \
-H 'Content-type: application/json' \
--data '{"channel":"C061EG9SL","text":"I hope the tour went well, Mr. Wonka.","attachments": [{"text":"Who wins the lifetime supply of chocolate?","fallback":"You could be telling the computer exactly what it can do with a lifetime supply of chocolate.","color":"#3AA3E3","attachment_type":"default","callback_id":"select_simple_1234","actions":[{"name":"winners_list","text":"Who should win?","type":"select","data_source":"users"}]}]}' \
https://slack.com/api/chat.postMessage```

Comment: This question is several years old now and I'm changed companies so don't have access to specifically what I had used at the time

Comment: Thanks that works! I was really looking for an example using a slack token. I can work with this to get where I need to be.